# How to filter maximum and minimum value in C code

Tags: c, visual-studio

Please see the C code below i dont understand how is it comparing -32000 to detect maximum value any number from 0 to 99 can be greater than -32000 . Similarly minimum value should be >= to zero , why set it to 32000. ???

```
    / MaxNumber.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
/* Promotes user enter an integer untile it detects 0 */
/* Fills a array buffer , and then finds minimum and maximum within it */

#include "stdafx.h"

#define MAX 100

int array[MAX];

int count = -1 , minimum, maximum, num_entered, temp ;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    puts("Enter integer values one per line ");
    puts(" Enter 0 when finished ");
    // do while to check the condition 
    //
    do 
    {
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        array[++count] = temp;
    } while ( count < (MAX-1) && temp != 0);
    ////////////////////////////////////////
    num_entered = count;
    //
    /* Find maximum and minimum value*/ 
    /* Set maximum to a very small value */
    /* Set minimum to a very large value */
    maximum = -32000;
    minimum = 32000;

    for ( count = 0; count <= num_entered && array[count] != 0; count++)
    {
        if ( array[count] > maximum )
            maximum = array[count];
        //
        // Now minimum 
        if ( array[count] < minimum )
            minimum = array[count];
    }
    //
    // Printing the results 
    printf("\n Maximum value entered is %d \n", maximum );
    //
    printf("\n Minimum value entered is %d \n", minimum );

    ////
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why does your file have a `.cpp` extension? Also why global variables?

Comment: Read the comments in the code, it's really bad code, but it has comments explaining what you want to know. Those values are not guaranteed to be small enough and are absolutely unecessary it would work well if you assign the first value in the array to each of `minimum` and `maximum` and then start looping from `count = 1`, don't you think? Also, the `scanf()` usage above is very wrong.

Comment: They are the initial seed values - the intention is for any number to be bigger/smaller than them. This is really bad code - don't use magic numbers like this.

Comment: This code was compiled in Microsoft visual C++ ver 6.0 as a windows console application , why scanf() is wrong ?

Comment: "They are the initial seed values - the intention is for any number to be bigger/smaller than them. This is really bad code - don't use magic numbers like this."

Comment: "They are the initial seed values - the intention is for any number to be bigger/smaller than them. This is really bad code - don't use magic numbers like this." this is not a logical explanation, ok what if i swap the values of maximum with that of minimum ?

Answer (score 0):

It starts by assuming the biggest value is a very small number. It should be the smallest possible number, but they picked -32000. It stores this value in the variable `maximum`.

It then iterates over the values stored in the array. When it finds a value bigger than the value stored in maximum, it replace the value stored in maximum by the biggest value. It continues until all values in the array have been examine. In the end `maximum` contains the biggest value in the array, unless all values in the array are smaller than -32000. In this case this implementation will fail.

A better implementation would initialize `maximum` and `minimum` with the first value of the array and examine the remaining elements of the array.

It could also have initialized `maximum` with the smallest possible value for an `int`. You have to include `limits.h` and use `INT_MIN`.

```
maximum = INT_MIN;
minimum = INT_MAX;
```

Comment: Thanks , it works , but what are the values of maximum = INT_MIN;
minimum = INT_MAX

Comment: You can print it to find out by yourself. There is also an UINT_MIN and UINT_MAX for unsigned int. There is the same for short and long. Look into limit.h to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever writing an algorithm of the kind "find the largest number", you simply loop through all numbers in the data and store the largest one you have found so far. For example

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
  if(data[i] > largest)
  {
    largest = data[i];
  }
}
```

In order to do the above, the variable `largest`where you store the largest one found, has to be properly initialized to the smallest possible value that the data can have.

The correct way to do that would have been to `#include <limits.h>` and then set

```
int largest = INT_MIN;
```

However, whoever wrote your code was too sloppy to do so. Instead they sloppily assumed that `int` is always 16 bits (which is not true), in which case the smallest possible value would be `-32767`. But because they were lazy/sloppy, they used the rounded value `-32000` instead, don't ask me why.

This means that the code simply won't work correctly for values smaller than -32000 (or greater than 32000). Furthermore, the code is non-portable. The standard Windows/Linux/whatever machine uses 32 bit `int`.

Please don't look at that code you have as a reference for learning/how to write proper programs. It is very poorly written.

Comment: What book do you suggest i read to write proper C code or more efficient code , is there an ebook  or a good website with tutorials and exercises ???